# Why is my mac terminal's ps -u not working?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, arguments, ps

I am learning the Linux ps command and its possible arguments. My tutorial told me about the -u argument and I am trying to use it.

No matter if I use it alone or with other args, it is throwing errors.

[I am inserting a picture of the output I keep receiving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKymV.png)
I'm not sure if this is something to do with my Mac's terminal/shell, or if I am missing something that I should be typing.

It seems to be telling me to use two hyphens, --u, instead of one, -u, but it gives me the same issue.
If I JUST have ps u, the terminal gives me the output, but if I try adding an f, fu, or f u, or -fu, the same issue occurs again.

Am I doing something wrong? I am just confused at this point how this all works and why I am not getting the output that all the tutorials are showing, with the same commands and args.

Comment: A brief history of `ps`: the Research UNIX version did not use `-` in front of options and did not have a `u` option. Berkeley added a `u` option. USG Unix started with Research UNIX and changed `ps` (and virtually every other command except for `dd`) to require `-` in front of options, and gave `ps` a bunch more options including `-u`, which was different from `u`. Many versions of `ps` today support both `u` and `-u`. Yes, it's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `ps` is expecting the `-u` flag to be followed with a username. So the command to use would be, e.g. `ps -u anotheruser`.

The Mac is based off of a BSD-variant of UNIX, which has some differences from the variants that grew up around GNU/Linux. So several commands may have different flags. I think the `-u` flag to `ps` is the same on both variants, but in general it's best to check the manpage for the command when following a Linux tutorial on Mac, or vice versa: `man ps`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Thank you!