# Mac Terminal command ps -A (and all other arguments) not working

Tags: macos, terminal, process

I'm experiencing a very similar problem to [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738806/why-is-my-mac-terminals-ps-u-not-working), but with "ps -A" (without the quotes of course and for all other arguments like -u, etc...). The output I receive is as follows:

```
    ps: illegal option -- f
    usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
              [-u]
              [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
           ps [-L]
```

I've tried the suggested solution found in the link above, e.g. ps -u [anotheruser], as well as looked for any other related answers I could find elsewhere on Stackoverflow and other various places online to no avail...

[I inserted a screenshot of my terminal input/output here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfg0r.png)

[I also inserted a screenshot of my terminal's output for "echo $SHELL" and "which ps" here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFzXZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your second image shows that the ps command is aliased to, "ps auxf". The alias is missing the -. It should be, "ps -auxf".

However, your alias has a second problem. The u flag takes an argument so it can not be in the middle of the flag group. To fix that your alias should be, "ps -axfu". that alias will always require an argument that is a user name. For example, "ps issac".

Comment: I went ahead and edited my post to include a screenshot of my terminal. I understand what you're saying regarding the argument tag and I appreciate the detailed explanation - it's very inciteful - but unfortunately, my question remains...

Comment: Is this the only shell command you are having a problem with? Commands like ls, pwd, and cd work correctly? I'm surprised to see, "~ @ MacBook-Pro-" *and* "=>" in your shell. Have you customized your shell prompt? Since PS is not acting as expected I would check that you are running in the shell you expect and that you are running the version of PS you expect. To check what shell you are running try "echo $SHELL" It should be something like "/bin/bash". To check where PS is coming from try, "which ps". It should be something like, "/bin/ps". Are you using the built in macOS Terminal.app?

Comment: To answer your first question, yes I did a long time ago in my .bash_profile and .bashrc. To answer your second question, yes: ls, pwd, and cd work correctly. Lastly, I added another screenshot of my Terminal's output for "echo $SHELL" and "which ps". Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Looks like you have an alias for ps which is invalid, “ps auxf”. The error is what I mentioned in the answer, the - is missing. Change the alias to, ps -auxf.